# How can I check within program whatever tests (written using MiniTest gem) are passing?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I want to end with something like

```
Tests = run_tests()
if !Tests.passed
   puts Tests.errors
   exit
end

start_function_running_for_a_long_time_using_now_verified_code()
```

Comment: To downvoter or somebody who is able to understand him/her - what was wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tests can be run from `my_tests.rb`, you could run them with a system call and use the exit status to determine if they passed:

```
`ruby my_tests.rb`

unless $?.success?
  abort "Tests didn't pass; aborting"
end

start_function_running_for_a_long_time_using_now_verified_code()
```

While it doesn't conditionally print the errors, it does stop execution if the tests failed.